# 3ds Max STL Export Resets Pivot

Tags: 3d-models

I am trying to modify the pivot of a STL file. Correct me at this point if this isn't even possible. So I load my obj in 3ds Max, center the pivot and center the object via the pivot in the world to 0 0 0.

Then I export my one selected centered object as a STL. After that I import the same stl again and the pivot is not centered. But the pivot isn't located at the original reset-point, it is slightly offset from the center. It looks like the centre of gravity. My object is a rim. How can I center the pivot in the STL?

Comment: You need to revisit what you are describing to us as 'pivot'. I assume you mean the origin of the STL object around which your slicer will rotate the object? I will take a guess that your slicer is only allowing you to rotate about a point of it's choice.

Comment: Solved it. It was a 3ds Max-problem. Worked just fine with blender.

Comment: Is there something you can post as a self-answer?

Comment: @SeanHoulihane Not really. Still don't know why this is behaving like this. Im exporting with Blener now. This works for me. But i'm still interested in a solution.

Comment: Hi Tom, Have you found a solution yet? Even if you haven't and are still waiting for someone to come up with an adequate solution, it could still be worth putting together your two comments and post them as a temporary workaround answer. You don't have to accept it (so that someone else will feel that they should post a solution), but your workaround could be useful for someone else with the same issue